# Javascript .onload not firing in IE? window.open reference issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, window-object

I haven't been able to make sense of the answers to related questions so far(down to my knowledge level), so...

I have a simple script(using jQuery) that opens a new window and adds certain content from the parent into a specified container inside the child. I'm not sure if it's my approach that's wrong or I'm just missing a step - the script to run on the new window runs in IE when it's outside of the `window.onload` function, but this breaks FF, and FF is happy when it's inside of the `window.onload`, but then the new window in IE doesn't appear to be doing anything(no alert, no add of content, nada).

Please can anybody explain to me why this is the case/what I'm doing wrong? Is it something to do with the reference to `window.open`?

This is the script:

```
var printPage = function(container){

    $('.printButton').click(function(){

        var printWindow = window.open('printWindow.html');  

        var contentFromParent = $(container).eq(0).html();   

        /*works for IE, but not FF
        printWindow.alert('works for IE, but not FF');  
        printWindow.document.getElementById('wrap').innerHTML = contentFromParent;*/

        /*works for FF and Chrome but not IE:*/
        printWindow.onload = function(){
            printWindow.alert('works for FF and Chrome but not IE');
            printWindow.document.getElementById('wrap').innerHTML = contentFromParent;          
        }

        /*I also tried:
        $(printWindow.document).ready(function(){
            printWindow.alert('load the page, fill the div');
            printWindow.document.getElementById('wrap').innerHTML = contentFromParent;
        }); //works for IE, not working for FF/Chrome*/
    })  
}
printPage('#printableDiv');
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <button href="#" class="printButton">Print</button>
    <div id="printableDiv"> 
        <p>I want to see this content in my new window please</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks for your pointers about onload in the new window - I've gone with this solution for now: [Setting OnLoad event for newly opened window in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245124/setting-onload-event-for-newly-opened-window-in-ie6) - simply checking the DOM and delaying the onload - working for IE7/8/9.

I'm not sure if you'd call it an 'elegant' solution, but it's working! Further comments, especially if you think this is flawed, would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
var newWinBody;
function ieLoaded(){
    newWinBody = printWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    if (newWinBody[0]==null){
        //page not yet ready
        setTimeout(ieLoaded, 10);
    } else {
        printWindow.onload = function(){
            printWindow.alert('now working for all?');
            printWindow.document.getElementById('wrap').innerHTML = contentFromParent;          
        }
    }
}
IEloaded();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open

Answer (score 3):

Can it be that the page you open fires the 'onload' event before you set the event handler `printWindow.onload = ...` ?

You might consider including some javascript in your 'printWindow.html' page. Let's say you add a short `<script>var printWindowLoaded = true;</script>` at the end of your page. Then your main script would do something like this:

```
function doStuff() {
        //...          
    }

if (printWindow.printWindowLoaded)
    doStuff();
else
    printWindow.onload = doStuff;
```

Comment: You were right, the onload was being fire too early. I couldn't actually find a simple way to apply your solution to my page, as the target html file doesn't exist, but your answer pointede me in the right direction. Thanks very much!