# Do Something When Window Loads

Tags: javascript, window, onload

I am trying to open an alert box when a window loads.  Here is what I have:

```
var imawindow = window.open("http://google.com");
imawindow.onload() = function () {
    alert("hey");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to show alert on the new window? or from the one it is opened ?

Comment: Open console and read the error. Then fix your code like `imawindow.onload = function`.

Comment: Even when you fix the syntax error (`onload() ` => `onload`) you cannot do this unless you are on the same domain. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245124/setting-onload-event-for-newly-opened-window-in-ie6).

Comment: I was wanting an alert box to pop up on the page that opened the window, not on the window that was opened.

Comment: Yes it will open the window from which it opened the new one. But for the same domain only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't execute it before you assign. Remove the `()`. If you wanna call the `alert` on the caller, then use `window.opener`:

```
imawindow.onload =  function () {
    window.opener.alert("hey");
}
```

And this should respect the **same domain policy**. The calling window, should be a relative page in your domain. Not something like you can call `http://www.google.com/` from `http://www.facebook.com/`. But you can call it from `index.html` on `hello.html`, provided that both `index.html` and `hello.html` are in from the same domain, say `http://example.com/index.html` and `http://example.com/hello.html`

Answer (score 0):

I would like mention that it will not work on cross-domain.

If you are opening a new page within the same domain than you will be able to achieve this by:

```
var imawindow = window.open("samedomainpage.html");
imawindow .addEventListener('load', functionToCall, false);
```

For cross-domain this will not work for security reasons. Read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Thanks!  So is there no way to execute a function on the original page when a new window (on a different domain) loads?

Comment: For the same-domain, **yes** . But for the cross-domain like you mentioned in question "google.com", the answer is **no**.

Comment: That's too bad.  Thanks!

Comment: Read here when it will work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules